# GUI Problems with Autoscaling

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, autoscaling

In our last update of our application something went wrong.
The application got problems with autoscaling.
Parts of the GUI is simply cut away.

[image]

The real problem though is that I cannot reproduce this. As allways it only appears on the clients setup.

The things that changed in the last update are the following:

1. an Update from VS 2015 to 2019
2. an update from 32 bit to 64 bit

Additionally the client is remotely connected to this location and I cannot connect to this location directly. This prevents me from reading out the scaling options since remote desktop seems to do some scaling itself and prevents you reading/changing the original values. I have not yet found where windows saves these values to ask the client to look them up and tell me for recreation purposes.

What could i try to fix it?

Does someone know where or how I could let the client look up the original scaling values for recreational purposes?

Edit 1: Framework: .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Edit 2: GUI is created via WinForms

Comment: You forgot to post your code and UI framework

Comment: Oh you are right. I will edit right away.